# Scraping iframe data in R

Tags: r, selenium, iframe, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a webpage using r , but the problem is that the scraped html contains just the iframe tag link- (http://mpe.motorolasolutions.com/?loc=US-EN&dest=Channel&_ga=1.41985443.782208401.1466659393) . Is there any way to get data from iframe tag in r using any package (preferable revst or RSelenium?

I want to scrape all(150) channel partner names in the above link (id=pagebody)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to scrape the contents of the iframe, can't you use `html_attr()` to get the iframe's source and then perform another scraping session for that url?